# How can I call object methods in the constructor of non initialized objects?

Tags: java, constructor

I have ui objects that allow me to overwrite their tick methods and I want to call other methods in these tick methods. But the way I'm doing it, the objects haven't been initialised yet so it's not working. 
Here's an example:

```
    //FPS       
    UITextRectangle fps = new UITextRectangle(
        handler, handler.getWidth()-64, 32, 32, 32, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY,
        new Ticker(){
          @Override
          public void doTick(){
            //cannot call fps
            fps.setText(Integer.toString(handler.getFPS()));
          }
        });
```

How can I make this work? Any and all help and advice is appreciated!

Edited because my code was wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get a compiler error? Exception?

Comment: I suggest to delete or close this questions, because it seems to be a typo problem...

Comment: "The local variable fps may not have been initialized" Because it's trying to call itself before it's finished initializing, sorry if you saw the code before I edited it. I messed it up the first time.

Comment: did answer with `final` worked?

Comment: Apologies for the sheer vanity of marking this a duplicate of a question that I asked and answered myself, but I think that this should give you a good idea as to why this isn't possible. Wouldn't `this.setText(...)` (or simply `setText(...)`) work?

Comment: @Flash `How can I call object methods in the constructor of non initialized objects?` Why can't you initialize the objects first? What is prevent you from doing that?

Comment: @AndyTurner It's an interesting answer, but I wouldn't say it's a good duplicate, as it doesn't give a possible solution to the specific problem here. This questions is not asking _why_ it occurs, it is asking for a workaround.

Comment: @JornVernee well, ok - but without information as to the available methods of the `UITextRectangle` (e.g. is there a `setTicker()` method?) it's hard to recommend the "correct" solution.

Comment: The Ticker interface has a `doTick()` method, the `UITextRectangle` has a `setText(String)` method. I could create a `setTicker()` method in `UITextRectangle` if that seems to be the best solution?

`setText(...)` does not work because it is a part of the `UITextRectangle` class, not the `Ticker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a the `Ticker` class, you could have a `doTick` template method:

```
class UITextRectangle {

    public void doTick() {
        // template method, is empty
    }
}
...
UITextRectangle tr = new UITextRectangle(...) {

    @Override
    public void doTick() {
        this.setText(...);
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!! I was starting to get lost with the technicalities of the other answers. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

try calling it directly, you dont need to use the fps object because you are in the callback of the object self

try this:

```
UITextRectangle fps = new UITextRectangle(handler, handler.getWidth()-64, 32, 32, 32, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, new Ticker(){
        @Override
        public void doTick(){ 
            setText(Integer.toString(handler.getFPS()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: But that would call ```setText``` on the ```Ticker```

Comment: i suppose to think that fps  has a method called settext()...

Comment: fps has the method setText(String text), the Ticker does not.

Answer (score 0):

create a property `UITextRectangle fps` in your class.

Another solution would be to set the `Ticker` after the initialization